# Updating sql server table everyday using external webservice

Tags: .net, sql-server

We are pulling data from an external web service, saving the data into a table.

The table has approximately 1900 rows. The scheduler runs everyday and table is updated everyday.

The way it is done is:

once the 1900 rows are ready as a list, the old 1900 rows are deleted(stored proc), the new ones are added(another stored proc).

But sometimes the external web service is not working properly. Because of that, the old rows are getting deleted but the new ones are not getting added. The table is empty as a result.

So, this is how I tackled the issue:

Rename current MyTable as MyTable_06072015

Create new table as MyTable and copy the new rows.

Delete yesterday's table - MyTable_06062015

I have a couple of questions now:

Is this the right solution for this issue?
Is there going to be any issue from SQL server side, renaming current table, creating a new table and deleting yesterday's table everyday?

Comment: I don't understand how *"once the 1900 rows are ready as a list"* matches to *"sometimes the external web service is not working"*. First you state that you know when to decide to clean the old values, then you state you end up with incomplete data. If you cannot validate the data extracted from the external web service, your (otherwise correct) alternative will fail just the same.

Comment: One word: Transaction. There's no need to rename tables or any other such nonsense. Start a transaction, delete the old data, add the new data, and commit the transaction. It's an all or nothing operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should tell us what you mean with "not working properly". For example, if you are getting a 500 http response because the webservice is not available sometimes, you could check the status of the webservice before delete the rows, if it is different than 20x, do nothing.

But if you dont mean that, probably you mean that the webservice is available, but is returning nothing because "I have no idea". You said that you are using a list. You could check the length of the list before delete the rows.

You are not going to have problems from sql side, but if I am not wrong you are deleting the old one only if the new one is empty right? As I said, you can do that before create/modify tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could run an update over the 1900 rows to essentially overwrite the preexisting data. However, you said approximately 1900 rows, so you might have to check if the number of new data rows is < old data rows, and then delete the difference. That way you wouldn't have to create or destroy whole tables.